# Git local alias and submodule foreach recursive

Tags: git, git-config

I am trying to define git local alias which can perform git command on all the submodules,
and it partly works but only for git commands or global alias. It seems that git submodule foreach --recursive does not read the .git/config,
and of cause I added the alias to all the submodels (using the same command).

The test has been performed on
#lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

**uname -a**

Linux spaceship 5.4.0-90-generic #101-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 15 20:00:55 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**git --version**

git version 2.25.1

**echo $SHELL**

/usr/bin/tcsh

I performed the following test.

Create a test repo

```
 mkdir git_config_test
 cd git_config_test
 git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/git_config_test/.git/
```

```
 ls -al
drwxrwxr-x  3 carsten carsten   4096 лис 27 15:13 .
drwxrwxrwt 34 root    root    143360 лис 27 15:13 ..
drwxrwxr-x  7 carsten carsten   4096 лис 27 15:13 .git

 echo "#Git config test" > README.mk
 git add README.md 
 git commit -am"First commit"
 git log
```

Define a local alias

```
 git config alias.fingerprint "rev-parse HEAD"
 git fingerprint
9202796e70acb5d247b74da5eb4d007253e73a38
```

Create a new repo for the submodule

```
 pwd
/tmp/git_config_test
 cd ..
 mkdir git_config_test_submodule.git
 cd git_config_test_submodule.git
 git init
 echo "#Git submodule" > README.md
 git add README.md
 git commit -am"First submodule commit"
```

Add the submodule to the module

```
 cd ../git_config_test
 git submodule add ../git_config_test_submodule.git 
 git commit -am"Submodule added"
 ls -al
total 160
drwxrwxr-x  4 carsten carsten   4096 лис 27 15:18 .
drwxrwxrwt 36 root    root    143360 лис 27 15:18 ..
drwxrwxr-x  8 carsten carsten   4096 лис 27 15:18 .git
-rw-rw-r--  1 carsten carsten     17 лис 27 15:14 README.md
drwxrwxr-x  3 carsten carsten   4096 лис 27 15:18
```

Now we added the alias to submodules also

```
 git submodule foreach --recursive git config alias.fingerprint 'rev-parse HEAD'
```

Check that the alias.fingerprint still works

```
 git fingerprint
d381bc4ce0d42e9c3f8062be496f7cb6d266f1b9
```

Check that the alias.fingerprint works in the submodule.

```
 cd git_config_test_submodule
 git fingerprint
1c7ddc2d79d0d7e8314540b03b6589c0876ee9a2
```

Now we define an alias to perform submodule recursive in the main repo

```
 pwd
/tmp/git_config_test
 git config alias.all 'submodule foreach --recursive'
```

We can test that the alias works.

```
 git all git rev-parse HEAD
Entering 'git_config_test_submodule'
1c7ddc2d79d0d7e8314540b03b6589c0876ee9a2
```

And we can check that the aliases have been defined for the main module.

```
 git --no-pager config --local --get-regexp alias 
alias.fingerprint rev-parse HEAD
alias.all submodule foreach --recursive
```

And we can also check that the aliases have been defined for the submodules by using the newly defined alias.all

```
 git all git --no-pager config --local --get-regexp alias
Entering 'git_config_test_submodule'
alias.fingerprint rev-parse HEAD
```

The **problem** is now, I would expect that alias.all would execute the aliases defined in the .git/config, but it seems that it doesn't see them for some reason.
As can be seen in the following test.

```
 git all git fingerprint
Entering 'git_config_test_submodule'
path='git_config_test_submodule'; fingerprint: 1: fingerprint: not found
fatal: run_command returned non-zero status for git_config_test_submodule
.
```

But it works if the alias has been defined in the ~/.gitconfig

```
 git all git --no-pager config --get-regexp alias|grep hash
alias.hash rev-parse HEAD
 git all git hash
Entering 'git_config_test_submodule'
1c7ddc2d79d0d7e8314540b03b6589c0876ee9a2
```

So I find this a little odd.

If somebody would give me a hint to what I am doing run. I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really have a question left at this point:

> It seems that `git submodule foreach --recursive` does not read the `.git/config` ...

That's correct—or wrong, depending on what you meant / how one reads it.  Each `git` command you run in the shell script you provide as an argument to `git submodule foreach` runs and reads `.git/config`.  But in:

```
(cd path/to/module; git foo; git submodule foreach --recursive git foo)
```

—which is what `git submodule foreach --recursive foo` runs when there's a `path/to/module` submodule at this layer—the `git foo` reads the `.git` that's in the Git repository that lives in `path/to/module`, i.e., `./path/to/module/.git/config`.  It does not read the `.git/config` that lives in `.`, `././.git/config`.

The fact that in modern Git, the submodule repositories are "absorbed" into the superproject `.git` directory, so that `path/to/module/.git` is a file instead of a directory, does not change the above, except for changing how Git ends up finding `.git/config` when `.git` is a file (Git reads the file to get the path to the repository, then reads and opens the config therein).

Hence, if you want a *local* alias that works in all the submodules, you must first use `git submodule foreach --recursive` to configure that alias into each submodule and each submodule's submodules.  If you have, say, 40 submodules counting recursively, you now have 41 copies of the alias: one local, and one in each of the 40 submodules.  Now you can `git foo` in each one.